# Are datetime objects cached?

Tags: python, datetime

I was tinkering around what it would take to get `False` from

```
print(datetime.now() == datetime.now())
```

I suppose that on every 'modern'/fast enough computer this will be `True`.

However, I've noticed something peculiar:

```
print(id(datetime.now()) == id(datetime.now()))
```

Will constantly output `True`, which led me to believe that `datetime` objects (probably just those created by `.now()`) are automagically cached somewhere.

Then I tinkered a bit more, and came up with this gem:

```
def get_now():
    now = datetime.now()
    print(id(now))
    return now

print(get_now() == get_now())
exit()
```

Now we get different IDs and the output is constantly `False`, as if the overhead of calling `get_now` twice was enough for the caching mechanism to understand the time changed and a new object was needed to be created.

I looked around at [datetime.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py) and couldn't find anything that will explain this behavior, so I suppose (if it even exists) it is implemented in the C level.

The word "cache" (or any of its conjugates) is not mentioned at all on the official [datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

Comment: No, it's not being cached. The ID is being reused by different objects.

Comment: Doing `id(x) == id(y)` is a common mistake; the lifetimes of `x` and `y` don't overlap and thus the ids *can* be identical even if the two objects are not. Always do `x is y` instead.

Comment: Apart from the `id()` explanation.... Precision is (can be) in nanoseconds (I am not sure and I would not presume that is true for all platforms and python implementations, but it applies  for cpython on Linux, and I presume POSIX/ish systems), even renewed request few instructions apart is actually yielding different results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no caching going on. Your code is roughly equivalent to:

```
temp = datetime.now()
id1 = id(temp)
temp = None
temp = datetime.now()
id2 = id(temp)
print(id1 == id2)
```

Clearing the variable after getting the ID allows the first `datetime` object to be garbage collected. The second `datetime` object reuses that memory, so they get the same ID.

If you write instead

```
temp1 = datetime.now()
temp2 = datetime.now()
print (id(temp1) == id(temp2))
```

you'll see that they're different.